# Rolling CPCs in BiqQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Disclaimer: I have very basic SQL skills, like "just walked in the door for the first time" level! So please be gentle.

I'm trying to set up a rolling CPC column. I have the following so far which works fine. But I can't figure out how to repeat column 7 as a rolling calculation.

```
WITH
  data AS(
  SELECT
    Date,
    Device_type,
    CASE
      WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Insertion_order,'.*Prospecting.*') THEN 'Prospecting'
      WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Insertion_order,'.*Retargeting.*') THEN 'Retargeting'
      WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Insertion_order,'.*Similar.*') THEN 'Similar Audience'
  END
    AS Strategy,
    ROUND(SUM(Total_media_cost__Advertiser_),2) AS Cost,
    SUM(Counter) AS Clicks,
    ROUND(CASE
        WHEN SUM(Counter) > 0 THEN SUM( Total_media_cost__Advertiser_) / SUM(Counter)
      ELSE
      0
    END
      ,2) AS CPC,

  FROM
    `data.data`
  GROUP BY
    Date,
    Device_type,
    Strategy)
SELECT
  Date,
  Device_type,
  Strategy,
  SUM(Cost) AS Cost,
  SUM(Clicks) AS Clicks,
  SUM(CPC) AS CPC,
  FROM
    data
  GROUP BY
    Date, Device_type, Strategy
```

[table from the above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brwl0.png)

I've read about `OVER` and added the following line but that threw a group by/aggregate error: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts

`CASE WHEN sum(Counter) > 0 THEN sum(Total_media_cost__Advertiser_) / sum(Counter) OVER (order by Date asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row)`

Any help is massively appreciated!

Comment: What is CPC?  What does your data look like?  What results do you want?

Comment: cost per click. So I'm looking for a rolling calculation over time for that metric, rather than just analysing the entire data set

Comment: Like the last column here basically: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EelR7FUYZOWbp12Q1AdV81FjB-JdI0HqZQBEFgsr0eM/

Comment: I've added some of the original data set also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit:**

Ok, just had a look at your spreadsheet. I think the code you've tried should work with a small modification. Would this work?

```
    WITH
  data AS(
  SELECT
    Date,
    Device_type,
    CASE
      WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Insertion_order,'.*Prospecting.*') THEN 'Prospecting'
      WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Insertion_order,'.*Retargeting.*') THEN 'Retargeting'
      WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Insertion_order,'.*Similar.*') THEN 'Similar Audience'
    END
    AS Strategy,
    ROUND(SUM(Total_media_cost__Advertiser_),2) AS Cost,
    SUM(Counter) AS Clicks,
    ROUND(CASE
          WHEN SUM(Counter) > 0 THEN SUM( Total_media_cost__Advertiser_) / SUM(Counter)
          ELSE 0
          END
          ,2) AS CPC,
  FROM
    `data.data`
  GROUP BY
    Date,
    Device_type,
    Strategy),
AggregateData as
(
  SELECT
      Date,
      Device_type,
      Strategy,
      SUM(Cost) AS Cost,
      SUM(Clicks) AS Clicks,
      SUM(CPC) AS CPC,
  FROM
      data
  GROUP BY
      Date,
      Device_type,
      Strategy
)

SELECT
  *,
  safe_divide(SUM(Cost) OVER (ORDER BY Date) , SUM(Clicks) OVER (ORDER BY Date)) as RollingCPC
FROM
  AggregateData
```

I've never tried dividing rolling sums but it should work.

---

**old reply**

I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, but you could try adding the following:

```
SUM(CPC) OVER(PARTITION BY Device_type, Strategy ORDER BY Date) AS RollingCPC
```

Comment: Thanks, but I dropped that in the final SELECT statement and that gives me the error:`SELECT list expression references column CPC which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [34:7]`

Comment: I've just had a look at your spreadsheet and modified the answer. Perhaps that would work?

Comment: That gives the error: `SELECT list expression references column Total_media_cost__Advertiser_ which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [21:39]`

I've put this in the first SELECT statment? Is that right!?

Comment: ok, one more attempt. fingers crossed it works this time :) I put your second block into another subquery, see if that works

Comment: Well that works without an error!! So I think we're nearly there! The calculation is grouped by date though, so not exactly like the Gsheet table, but so close. I've updated the Gsheet so you can see what I mean.

Thanks ErrHuman!

Comment: I see what you mean. I guess at this point you may want to consider that information does the rolling CPC is actually telling you. because the way you have it set up currently on your spreadsheet t doesn't actually say anything meaningful until you've gathered all the date for a day (at which point the BQ and your spreadsheet match). You could group it by the device type and strategy and this way the most current day would give you a rolling sum for each strategy and each device which might be more meaningful depending what you want to do with that information.

Comment: if you want to keep the current logic though you could add the strategy and device type in "ORDER BY" clause together with the Date:

safe_divide(SUM(Cost) OVER (ORDER BY Date,Device_type, Strategy) , SUM(Clicks) OVER (ORDER BY Date,Device_type, Strategy)) as RollingCPC

Comment: Thanks Err. I was thinking the same thing re. what the data is actually saying. It's working really well now! I'm actually using this in Data Studio with a paramater select option for device and strategy, and it's all working well! Thanks again man!